# php My foreach loop dont echo out

Tags: php, foreach

```
include 'api/apiBase.php';
$farray[] = GetUserFriends($login->User_id);
foreach ($farray as $FID) 
{
    echo "$FID \n";
}
```

My foreach loop won't echo out the array.
the function that i have GetUserFriends Returns 2 variables in a array.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with: *won't echo out the array* nor do I know what your question is.

Comment: What does `var_dump($farray)` shows?

Comment: Change this line `$farray[] = GetUserFriends($login->User_id);` to `$farray = GetUserFriends($login->User_id);` yours added another level to the array

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output? If `GetUserFriends` returns an array, there is no need for the `[]` on `$farray`. To see the output of `$farray`, do `var_dump($farray);` and you will be able to see what the data looks like.

Comment: @u_mulder it shows
array (size=1)
    0 => 
    array (size=1)
         0 => string '8' (length=1)

Comment: @user3050767 That's because you're putting the friends array inside another array, like several comments say.

Comment: Is that before or after you removed the unnecessary `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok comments dont seem to be working so change your code to this

```
include 'api/apiBase.php';

// following line changed
$farray = GetUserFriends($login->User_id);

echo $login->User_id . ' has ' . count($farray) . ' friends';

foreach ($farray as $idx => $value) 
{
    echo "Friend $idx has FriendId $value \n";
}
```

This line `$farray[] = GetUserFriends($login->User_id);` with the extra `[]` in is adding another level to the `$farray` that you dont need and is confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

> That's because you're putting the friends array inside another array, like several comments say. –  Barmar

Ohh the error was in my function :) Thanks